# What's the probability of a future polling result falling in a given range?

Tags: statistics

### Question

Each day, Gallup polls U.S. Employee Engagement. You can see [7-day rolling averages of the daily numbers here](http://www.gallup.com/poll/180404/gallup-daily-employee-engagement.aspx).

Assume you have a set of historical daily numbers (ie, `[0.354827, 0.352648, 0.34943, …]`). **What would be the best technique to estimate the probability of a future number falling in a given range?**

> As an example, I may want to say "the probability of the number three days from now falling in the range `0.45…1` is ____%."

### Initial Attempt

My initial attempt counted the # of times this range condition had been met in the last 90 days, but this has a number of flaws. Most notably, the ranges `0…0.01` and `0…0.15` were equally unlikely, but obviously the former should be less likely than the latter.

That is, my initial attempt didn't consider that the results tend to hover around `0.30…0.33`.

### Related Questions

I read [Continuously sampled event: Estimating the value of a future data point, based on past measurements and their tendency](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191743/72677). The question seemed related, but not identical, and the answer was over my head. I started [reading about ARIMA models](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8), but I didn't want to get too far into the weeds without knowing if that's the right approach here.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to what is known as a [Credible Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) which is [similar but distinct from a confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval). Credibility intervals are constructed using a probability of correctness expressed as a percentage. This is the percent chance that the true value falls within the interval. What you wish to do is reverse engineer a credibility interval: go from an interval to a percentage.

Comment: Could you expand your answer with an example? How would you use this with the Employee Engagement data?